# Show all partitions a user can access in SLURM

Tags: slurm

I'm converting a script from SGE to SLURM.

In SGE, the script generates a list of which queues the user $USER can access -

```
$ qstat -U $USER -g c

CLUSTER QUEUE                   CQLOAD   USED    RES  AVAIL  TOTAL aoACDS  cdsuE
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1-day                             0.1      1      0   2999   3000      0      0
1-hour                            0.1      0      0   3000   3000      0      0
30-day                            0.1      1      0   1999   2000      0      0
```

How do I see which partitions a given user can access in SLURM? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe have a look at [sacctgmr](https://slurm.schedmd.com/sacctmgr.html). Using our cluster

```bash
sacctmgr show User $USER --associations
```

leads to:

| User | Def Acct | Admin | Cluster | Account | Partition | Share | Priority | MaxJobs | MaxNodes | MaxCPUs | MaxSubmit | MaxWall | MaxCPUMins | QOS | Def QOS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | YYY | None | ZZZ | xa |  | 1000 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  | long,normal,short |  |
| XXX | YYY | None | ZZZ | all |  | 1000 |  | 1000 |  |  | 5000 |  |  | long,normal,short |  |

the QOS is probably what you want.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! On my server, this gives one row per partition that the user can see

Comment: Yeah, the same at our cluster. you can additionally use `-p` or `-P` get a parsable output. If it helps, please accept the answer :)